# How can I network two laptops?

Tags: network-shares

Is there a simple way to connect two HP laptops?  These are standalone computers.  One should be the client, while the other act as a server.

Comment: For what services?

Comment: For network connection?

Answer (score 1):

Use a crossover cable, set the IPs statically to be on the same subnet and use the server's IP address as the gateway:

```
Client: 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
Server: 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
```

You will only be able to connect them to each other, and must reference them by IP and not by machine name.

Comment: The mask in your example should be "255.255.255.0". There is no need for cross-over cable if either NIC is a gigabit one. Also originally the question had the [wireless-networking] tag - did Craig change his mind?

Comment: @AlexP. +1 for the Gbit, I tried to make sure he wasn't referring to wifi only, didn't see any indicator.